# Circular loading image rotating very off center in CSS animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a website where there is a loading icon for five seconds so the page can load. I have no trouble with that. The problem is that the loading icon is rotating off-center. Think about as if you put a circle on a pencil and spun it. That is what is looks like. https://mandalorian.elliott23.repl.co
That is the website. This is the CSS and HTML.

```css
.loader-wrapper img{
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: .8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes spin{
  from{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-wrapper">
  <img src="+load.svg" width="120px">
</div>
```

I have tried using `transform-origin: center;` and `-webkit-transform-origin: center;`, neither of those have worked. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the image in an image editor. It is not centered. Replace that svg with a centered one.

Comment: Didn't work. I don't know why.